# react-native-maps - can you dismiss an event?

Tags: react-native, events, react-native-maps

In a MapView event, such as onRegionChange, is there a way to dismiss it -- that is, to have it not execute?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you're more specific about your code and what you want to happen. You could only send the callback as a prop under certain conditions, for example, but I don't know enough about your situation to say it'll work for you.

Comment: you can pass the prop:  pointerEvents='none' to the mapView, this may help you.

Comment: @scrayne have you tried the pointerEvents ?

Answer (score 0):

try to add pointerEvents="none" prop on the mapView This may help you.